# Using Delphi predefined conditional symbols for cross-platform code containing assembly code

Tags: delphi

This is my first effort to write a cross-platform program using Delphi.

I have read the following topics in Delphi XE8 Documentation:

- [Using Inline Assembly Code](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Using_Inline_Assembly_Code#Using_Conditional_Defines_for_Cross-Platform_Code)
- [Various Ways You Can Enter Compiler Directives](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Delphi_compiler_directives#Various_Ways_You_Can_Enter_Compiler_Directives)`

Both articles recommend the following construction when using predefined conditional symbols for cross-platform code:

```
function TheFunc(x: Integer): Integer;
{$IFDEF PUREPASCAL}
begin
  // Pascal implementation here...
end;
{$ELSE !PUREPASCAL}
{$IFDEF CPUX86}
  asm
    // ASM implementation here...
  end;
{$ENDIF CPUX86}
{$ENDIF !PUREPASCAL}
```

I didn't find the definition or the description of the predefined symbol `PUREPASCAL` on the website [docwiki.embarcadero.com](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/) through my googling. My understanding for now is that the `{$IFDEF PUREPASCAL}` means the code in that context will be compiled if assembler is not supported for the target platform. Please confirm ... Do I understand it correctly?

Therefore my actual question is ... Why the examples provided by the documentation suggests prioritizing `{$IFDEF PUREPASCAL}` than `{$IFDEF CPUX86}`? Compiling the above function in x64 mode should fail.

Why not just as follows?

```
function TheFunc(x: Integer): Integer;
{$IFDEF CPUX86}
  asm
    // ASM implementation here...
  end;
{$ELSE}
begin
  // Pascal implementation here...
end;
{$ENDIF}
```

This way, the Pascal (non-assembly) code is guaranteed to be compiled in case assembler is not supported for the target platform.

Comment: PUREPASCAL isn't defined by the compiler. Why are you wanting to write asm anyway?

Comment: I just write asm for a very simple problem such as calculating base-2 log. Using asm for such problem is easy, that is `BSR EAX, EAX` for 32-bit code, and `BSR RAX, RCX` for 64-bit code.

Comment: Indeed PUREPASCAL isn't defined/self-activated when you switch to the 64-bit platform. You can define it yourself in Project Options -> Compiling - Conditional Defines. But do it for the 64-bit platform only! (Not also for 32bit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PUREPASCAL` isn't defined by the compiler. It's used by some libraries to allow the developer to override the default setting and force the use of Pascal. But you'd normally have the Pascal code enabled either by `PUREPASCAL` or the target platform not having an asm version implemented.

You can use that approach if you wish, but for routine development there's not a lot to be said for it. Your approach is fine. Go ahead with it.

Comment: I see. Thank's so much.

Comment: `PUREPASCAL` is also used by Embarcadero's RTL itself.  For example, here is a snippet from XE5's `SysUtils` unit: `{$IFDEF CPUX86}
  {$DEFINE X86ASM}
{$ELSE !CPUX86}
  {$DEFINE PUREPASCAL}
  {$DEFINE PUREPASCAL_X64ONLY}
{$ENDIF !CPUX86}`